# Generating variable name dynamically

Tags: java, php, c++, c, perl

i just want to know is there any method in current programming languages where a variable name like an array can be generated dynamically for example.,

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    int a <concatenation operator> i = <some logic on variable i>;
    printf("the value generated in the logic is %d",a <concatenation operator> i);
}
```

i know there is a concept of arrays in the similar way but i just want to know if this exists in any programming language.

thanks in advance....

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and think about what you want to *achieve* rather than the way you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: PHP has *variable variables*. Javascript has dynamic object indexes, and everything is an object in JS, even the current scope. Other languages have similar mechanisms I suppose. No, it is not sane to use this kind of thing 99% of the time.

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet i just want to know if there is any thing in present languages which has the above feature or not..

Comment: As you even wrote in the question, that is what arrays are for!!! I'm curious: **what would this be useful for?** Also, on a side note, with a squint I can imagine one context the 'generate unique variable names' use case could actually be useful: when generating code using templates. But that is not a runtime action, that is done pre-compile time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval perhaps, but I wouldn't use it.

To add to Jon Skeet's comment, doing this sort of thing may be possible but is ill-advised for many reasons.