# How do I make a progression with a variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables

I am interested in how to call a variable that changes, such as `customer1`, `customer2`, `customer3`, etc. These customer variables are populated in this particular `Class`. I would like the program to automatically type that number when I perform something such as `customer1.returnName();` if the user types a `1`. without me making a case by case code. I would like the user to type the number of the customer and it automatically uses that number. What function is best for this?

Comment: Use an array, or a `Map<Integer, Customer>`

Comment: You don't want a "progression" with a variable, but rather you want an "association", an association of a number with a specific Customer. An array or ArrayList would work well too if your numbers are monotonically increasing always and are stable.

Comment: The solution from @ElliottFrisch is a good one. However, also see why this question is problematic at [Increment Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762848/increment-variable-names), or [Generating variable name dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286516/generating-variable-name-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbered variables, then use a list. Something like

```
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

customers.add(new Customer("name"));

customers.get(0).returnName();
```